# FlatList doesn't show whole list until swipe down in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, algolia

I'm trying to figure out how to show the whole list in more than 2 `FlatList`.

If I use 2 flat lists on One screen, It can't show correctly. Because of the one flat list of above, the height of `FlatList` of the bottom can not show the whole list I guess.

Here's my code.

**Item List**

```js
// Hits.js
<FlatList
    data={hits}
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {
                    item.city ? imgUrl = require('...') : imgUrl = require('...')
                }
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => item.city ? this.props.moveToDetail(item.name) : this.props.moveToList(item.name)}
                    style={styles.separator}>
                    {
                        this.searchListRender(item, imgUrl)
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }}
    // getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
    //     {length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index}
    // )}
/>
```

**Algolia Search**

```js
<InstantSearch
    appId={ALGOLIA_APP_ID}
    apiKey={ALGOLIA_API_KEY}
    indexName={ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME}
>
    <View
        style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: '#f90631',
            padding: 10
        }}
    >
        <SearchBox _onKeyPressed={this._onKeyPressed}/>
    </View>
    {
        flag ?
            <Fragment>
                <View>
                    <Text>Tags</Text>
                    <Index indexName={ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME}>
                        <Hits moveToList={this.moveToList}/>
                    </Index>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text>Stores</Text>
                    <Index indexName="stores">
                        <Hits moveToDetail={this.moveToDetail}/>
                    </Index>
                </View>
            </Fragment>
            : null
    }

</InstantSearch>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        .....//FLatlist 1
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        .....//FLatlist 2
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: If I give the style of flex:1 into the parent view, it wouldn't show anything. Besides, both of children's flex:1 will make the height of children's flatlist same. I'd like know how to set dynamically flatlist

Comment: Let say you are not giving flex or any height to first flatlist, what height will it take(what if it has 100 data) ? where will second flatlist start? Obviously second flatlist will beneath first one and if first flastlist has height more than screen hight then second will be never shown. So bottom line you need to fix your usable area for both flatlist, if not same then use different flex sizes or use `height:"50%"` or any other number instead of flex.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know the size of height. So, I can't set both of flat lists' height. That's why I was looking for how to set the height of flat list dynamically. Hmm... do you have any idea?